# Unable to compare values

Tags: java, excel

I have a class named `"Read"` where I am reading the values of a specific cell `A1` of an Excel sheet and then putting that value in a variable `"Cellresult"`. In another class `"Patient"` I am trying to compare the value of a text field with id `"txtVFNAME"` against the variable I just created for the specific cell.
I am doing as below for that cell reading and variable storage (it's working fine).

```
public class Read {

public String Cellresult;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Workbook workbook = null;
    Sheet sheet = null;
    String Cellresult;

        try {
            workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("D:\\rptViewer.xls"));
        } catch (BiffException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);

        int columNumber = 0;
        int rowNumber = 1;

        Cell a1 = sheet.getCell(columNumber,rowNumber);
        Cellresult = a1.getContents();
        System.out.println(Cellresult);

        if(a1.getContents().equalsIgnoreCase("HAJI NIGAR")){
            System.out.println("Found it");
        }       
    }  
}
```

For comparing values, I tried below in the class `"Patient"`, but nothing printed:

```
Read compare = new Read ();
WebElement a = idriver.findElement(By.id("txtVFNAME"));
if (a.equals(compare.Cellresult)){
     System.out.println("text is equal");
};
```

I am using Java, IE 10, Win 8, Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

You have two different `String Cellresult;`s declared. The one inside the `main` is the one that will get initialized with a value, but the class member `Cellresult` is still null. So when you try and access it from another class, it has no value.

Maybe delete the one inside and make the outer one `static`

Comment: sorry, i didnt get it. can you please be kind enough to guide how to fix. Many thanks.

Comment: Try deleting the `Cellresult` inside the `main` method and making the outer one `static`. `public static String Cellresult;`

Comment: the second part of code i pasted is still not printing anything :(
I tried to print "a" and the result was  [[InternetExplorerDriver: internet explorer on WINDOWS (630c9017-41c6-4f19-8b18-872202bd2276)] -> id: txtVFNAME]

Comment: Did you try and print out both to see if they are equal? Both `compare.Cellresult` _and_ `a`?

Comment: System.out.println(compare.Cellresult);  is prinitng null :(

Comment: In your `main` method, print out `a1.getContents()` see what you get.

Comment: in my class read, i wrote: 
if(a1.getContents().equalsIgnoreCase("HAJI NIGAR")){
    System.out.println("Found it");
    System.out.println(a1.getContents()); and it printed  "HAJI NIGAR"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43425/discussion-between-haseeb-and-peeskillet)

Answer (score 0):

just remove your `String Cellresult;`

in your main you currently use `Cellresult = a1.getContents();`

This currently reffers to your local variable `CellResult`. In your compare part, you refer to the property `Cellresult` which is not the same. You have set a value of your local variable. Your property remains empty, resulting in a compare method that compares with nothing

Comment: just remove "String Cellresult;" inside of your main methode. (3d line in your main methode).

Comment: i have removed it and changed the class Cellresult to:
    public class Read {
 public static String Cellresult;

still no printing :(

Comment: also, in your patient class, you create a new instance of Read(). This does not make it run your main method. either make the Celresult in your read class static (and make sure the main is used before your call) or just run it yourself